# Trying to connect to a Digitalocean App with docker results in error: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist

Tags: docker, digital-ocean, docker-daemon

I'm trying to locally access a Digitalocean app that was made on their App Platform. Their docs mention to use docker but I'm very new to it: https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/build-locally/

I have docker installed, a docker daemon socker running, and their CLI.

When I run `doctl app dev build` it asks me which app I want to connect to so it looks like the connection to my Digitalocean account is working but when I select the app and it asks me if I want to use environment variables I have on local, it results in this error:

Error: creating build container: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/bp-app/.do/cache/{name-of-digitalocean-app}

I've ran it a few times and tried using env variables vs not using them. I just keep getting stuck with his error.

Comment: Please provide a minimal repro of your issue so that we may help. The error suggests (!?) that `doctl` is using `docker` to try to mount a non-existent directory into the container in order to build your app (and failing) but without additional details (code), it's difficult to help.